# Remove completely the row if value of column A exist in other row of column A

Tags: excel, vba

How to change the code below to use a specific sheet called "name", not the active sheet?
The goal is to delete the entire row if the value in column A is duplicate with values in same column, which works if I am in the sheet.

```
Sub delete_duplicates_column_A()

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:L")
        .Value = .Value 'removes formulas
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes ' remove duplicates only on column A
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub delete_duplicates_column_A()

    With Sheets("name").Range("A:L")
        .Value = .Value 'removes formulas
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes ' remove duplicates only on column A
    End With


End Sub
```